# Inputted activities can not be displayed for one specific user but can be seen by others

Tags: activities, acl

A Civi user with Manager's rights asked this:

The activities part of a volunteers file on Civi: although it may say 2 activities in the tabs, when I click on it, it says that there are no activities.

However when another Manager and myself (Administrator) log in, the activities are visible.

Why is this occurring?